# Массив задаваемой длины

Tags: c

А в Си можно массив объявить такой, чтобы размер определился при исполнении?

```
void allocate(int size)
{
    int sample[size];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, такой массив можно определить в C99. В частности, [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) это позволяет.

Answer (score 3):

```
void allocate(int size)
{
    int* sample = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    ..
    freemem(sample);
}
```

[Malloc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc)

Comment: ммм спасибо но я имел в виду именно массив на стеке

Comment: alloca(sizeof(int) * size);

Answer (score 0):

Могу вам предложить создать массив с применением ООП подхода. А именно реализовать методы для выделения памяти, добавление элемента, получение элемента по индексу и освобождения памяти. Вот вам пример:

*Заголовочный файл: List.h*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 100

typedef int ListItem;

extern ListItem *list_not_found;

typedef struct {
    int length;
    int capacity;
    ListItem *items;
} List;

List* list_init();
void list_add(List *list, ListItem item);
ListItem* list_get(List *list, int index);
void list_clear(List *list);
```

*Реализация динамического листа в файле: List.m*

```
#include "List_s.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

ListItem *list_not_found;

List* list_init()
{
    static int static_list_nil;
    if (!list_not_found)
        list_not_found = &static_list_nil;
    List *newList = malloc(sizeof(List));
    *newList = (List){.capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY, .length = 0, .items = malloc(DEFAULT_CAPACITY*sizeof(ListItem))};
    return newList;
}

void list_add(List *list, ListItem item)
{
    if (list->length >= list->capacity)
    {
        list->capacity *= 2;
        list->items = realloc(list->items, sizeof(ListItem)*list->capacity);
    }
    list->items[list->length++] = item;
}

ListItem* list_get(List *list, int index)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < list->length)
        return &list->items[index];
    return list_not_found;
}

void list_clear(List *list)
{
    free(list->items);
}
```

**Пример использования:**

```
#include "List_s.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    List *newList = list_init();

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        list_add(newList, i);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        ListItem *item = list_get(newList, i);
        if (item != list_not_found)
            printf("List[%d]=%d\n", i, *item);
        else
            printf("List[%d] - not found\n", i);
    }

    list_clear(newList);
    return 0;
}
```

**Итог:**

- В данной реализации, список при иницализации (метод `list_init()`)
  выделяет память по умолчанию для *DEFAULT_CAPACITY* элементов.
- В качестве элемента, в данном примере используется тип *int*. Тип
  хранимых элементов может быть и структурой, для этого неодходимо
  указать тип структуры в строке `typedef int ListItem;`
- Для добавления и получения элементов списка использовать методы:  `void
  list_add(List *list, ListItem item) и ListItem* list_get(List *list,
  int index)`.
- После завершения работы со списком необходимо освободить память `void list_clear(List *list)`

Comment: Не находите, что несколько странно называть структуру данных, которая по сути является `vector`-ом List? Да и название файла как-то "близковато" к довольно широко известному [/linux/include/linux/list.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/list.h). / И наконец, вопрос определенно был о выделении памяти в стеке, а не в куче.

Comment: Имя структуры `List`  я использовал только для примера, что бы показать аналогию с ООП (класс `List` в java). В этом примере я хотел продемонстрировать, каким способом удобно создавать динамические списки данных, не задумываясь об выделении, освобождении памяти, а использовать методы для простой работы с списком. В данной реализации память выделяется в куче, потому что, к несчастью, на размер стека наложены произвольно выбранные ограничения, поэтому стек гораздо меньше памяти общего назначения. А наборы данных бывают иногда очень большими, что приводит к использованию `malloc`.   @avp

Comment: Вышеприведенный код все таки реализует классический вектор, а не список. List в Java - это просто интрефейс, который не указывает, как именно хранить элементы, а только говорит о том, что должен уметь класс, который его реализовывает. Также есть класс ArrayList, который дополнительно запутывает.(как по мне - так очень плохое название - массив списков или массив-список?)